# GCE Ingress resource and ClusterIP service

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have simple ingress for virtual hosting:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-access
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service1.domain.com
    http: 
      paths:
      - backend:     
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
  - host: service2.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 80
```

Services service1 and servcie2 have definitions like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1
  labels:
    chart: "chart"
spec:
  type: ClusterIP # LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: web
  selector:
    app: service1
```

If I deploy services with type `ClusterIP` they don't work, ingress responds with error:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Then I change type of one of the services to `LoadBalancer`, it gets external IP and I can access it using this external IP, and also I can access it though ingress (using host name `service1.domain.com`)

If I try to access service2 (service2.domain.com - which still has type `ClusterIP`) ingress responds with:

```
default backend - 404
```

If I change servcice2 type to `LoadBalancer` it starts to work through ingress.

I think that ingress should work with `ClusterIP` services, because LoadBalancer service type assigns external IP, which is not needed at all, and if I get it correctly gcloud ingress resource by default should use its own load loadbalancer.

So what is wrong with the setup?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/docs/faq/gce.md

It seems that the correct answer is that Ingress requires NodePort to work with, so services should have `NodePort` type for this case.